# Select2 load data with Ajax from file

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a script called `listofValues.php`, which queries a database and returns JSON format values.

What I need is to pass these values to the `select2` `data` member. I need it to load once.

I don't need to pass values from `select2` input (term) to my `listofValues.php` as described in [this example](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#ajax)

```
$('#select2div').select2({
        //data:[],
    ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "listofvalues.php",    
        success: function (data) {          
        }
    }
```

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 29):

### Simple Example

It would be useful to know the format of the object you're getting back from `listofvalues.php`, but let's just assume, for the sake of simplicity it looks like this:

```
[ {"id": 1, "text": "option1"},
  {"id": 2, "text": "option2"},
  {"id": 3, "text": "option3"} ]
```

This is the easiest format to use, as by default, `select2` can handle objects with property names `id` and `text` and render them into a dropdown list. So your `select2` initialisation might look like this:

```
$('#select2div').select2({
    ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "listofvalues.php",
        results: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    }
});
```

### Slightly Trickier Example

Now let's assume the data from `listofvalues.php` doesn't follow the convenient naming conventions:

```
[ {"id": 1, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Lennon"},
  {"id": 2, "firstName": "Paul", "lastName": "McCartney"},
  {"id": 3, "firstName": "George", "lastName": "Harrison"},
  {"id": 4, "firstName": "Ringo", "lastName": "Starr"} ]
```

We'll have to set up a function to handle the output:

```
function formatValues(data) {
    return data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName;
}
```

And our `select2` initialisation:

```
$('#select2div').select2({
    ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "listofvalues.php",
        results: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    },
    formatResult: formatValues
});
```

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Sad times :( Which part, the first example, or the second? Knock up a JSFiddle and I'll take a look :D

Comment: I figured out. The json requires quotes around the keys:
[ {"id": "1", "text": "option1"},{"id": "2", "text": "option2"},{"id": "3", "text": "option3"} ]
Hope this helps. Maybe that's why your answer didn't get picked as the right answer.

Comment: Good catch. The JSON wasn't really part of my answer, I just took a guess at what the OP's PHP was delivering. I'll update, since having correctly-formed JSON will improve the example :) Who knows why the OP never got back to me

Comment: @simon How is the value specified?

Comment: @chris Sorry, which value do you mean?

Comment: @simon nevermind, realized "id" attribute is the value, thought that it had to be an int value or something.

I was talking about the actual value of the selected input. what gets submitted to the form, that is.