# Can't get select2 to work with a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-select2

I am trying to get select2 to work with an external json-file:
The json-file looks like this (it is called data.json and is in the root directory of my Website):

```
{"laender":[
    {
        "Land"  :   "Ägypten",
    "kurz"  :   "EG",
        "Fahne" :   "aegypten"

    },
    {
        "Land"  :   "Andorra",
        "kurz"      :       "AN",
        "Fahne" :   "andorra"
    }
]}
```

The Javascript Looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
function formatValues(data) {
   return data.Land + ' ' + data.Fahne;
}
$('#countrySelect').select2({
    ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "data.json",
        results: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    },
    formatResult: formatValues
});
```

(As mentioned here: [Select2 load data with Ajax from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490609/select2-load-data-with-ajax-from-file)).
The Output in HTML is a simple

```
<div id="countrySelect"></div>
```

But I can't get it to work. I tried so many things but nothing happens. Also I am rather new to json and Ajax.

Thanks for any help in advance!
Dietmar

Comment: do you see any errors in developer console?

Comment: Select2: The AJAX results did not return an array in the `results` key of the response. This is the error message, but I don't have a clue how to fix that...

Comment: can you put a `console.log("AJAX data",data)` as the first statement after `function(data) {`starts and change `results` to `success`  ?

Comment: Okay, I opened the console using IE Developer Tools. As mentioned above the message "The AJAX results did not return an Array in the 'results' key of the Response. But when I open up the Ajax data [object Object], there is an entry called 'laender' as an Array with all Information...

Comment: But how can I continue???

Answer (score 1):

your javascript code is for old version select2 below 4.0.0. if you using select2 4.0.0, then you must using processResult instead of result.

try to change these lines

```
results: function (data) {
    return {results: data};
}
```

to like this

```
processResults: function (data) {
    return {results: data};
}
```

for additional info, select2 4.0.0 doesn't support input hidden anymore. so, your #countrySelect must be select element rather than hidden input.

sorry my bad english

reference:
[select2 4.0.0 ajax documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html#ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Your keys in json is:

```
"Land", "kurz", "Fahne",
```

but select2 in this case expect:

```
"id", "text"
```

to make: `<option value="id"> text </option>`

You should use map function:

```
processResults: function(data){
                 return {
                  results: $.map(data, function(smthg){
                   return { id: smthg.kurz, text: smthg.Fahne }
                  })
                 };
                }
```

its example, i don't know which values You want use, and i use json like:

```
   [
    {"id_pr":"1252","pr":"aaa"},
    {"id_pr":"1253","pr":"bbb"}
     ...
   ]
```

and it works, but
i didn't try:

```
{   laender: [
              {"id_pr":"1252","pr":"aaa"},
              {"id_pr":"1253","pr":"bbb"}
]}
```